# How to use PolyLine to draw path between two coordinates in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift

This method is mentioned and explained in apple's documentation. Can someone guide me on how to use it ?

```
 convenience init(coordinates coords: CMutablePointer<CLLocationCoordinate2D>, count: Int)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* use it like this:

```
let c1 = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0.0, longitude: 0.0)
let c2 = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 1.0, longitude: 1.0)
var a = [c1, c2]

var polyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: &a, count: a.count)
```

I can't see a "Swifter" way to create MKPolylines in the docs... I assume they are still building the bridge, here.